# Selenium failing to set value with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set the value of a "textarea" element using Javascript since SendKeys() isn't working very well. The script is working well for test1 but failing on test2. I am thinking it may not be liking the newline character. Any thoughts?

```
string test1 = "City\tState\tBilling Card Station Code\tRetail Price\tBest Discounted Price\tDiscount";
                            
string test2 = "City\tState\tBilling Card Station Code\tRetail Price\tBest Discounted Price\tDiscount\nLoxley\tAL\tAL821\t5.5890\t4.6821\t0.9069";

string commandJs = $"document.getElementById('sourceData').value='{test2}';";

((IJavaScriptExecutor)_chromeDriver).ExecuteScript(commandJs);
```

Comment: There's 2 things wrong with this. 1) You set the textarea text with innerText and 2) You need to pass the variable as an argument to ExecuteScript

Comment: What do you mean by "failing?" Are you getting an exception? If so, please [edit] your question to include the error message and stack trace. Otherwise, please clarify what you mean by "failing."